# javascript convert math text into latex/graphic

Tags: javascript, html, math, latex

I am trying to find a plugin that can convert this text

```
1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^1 = 1 + 0 + 3 = 5
```

into latex so it can be more **easily readable** and **user friendly**

I dont mind if i need to make simple modifications on the syntax...

Comment: What LaTeX do you see this getting turned into? This does not seem hard to generate code from...

Comment: i would like the multiply symbol to be a little more readable(probably can CSS it) but also the ^1 to actual turn into an exponent...

Comment: That's not LaTeX. **What output would you like from that input?**

Comment: As I said I want to stylize the symbols * and ^ to be easily viewable...

Comment: I repeat: that's not LaTeX. Figure out and tell us exactly what output you want. I'm done here.

Comment: Are you looking for something like MathJax? http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: @MattBall i didnt say its Latex i also added the graphic in the title since i wasnt sure... what i asked is if i can convert it into latex with little modification, thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a very basic markup, regular expressions are your friend.

The following example replaces each `*` with a middle dot · and adds some HTML markup (`<sup>`) to create those exponents. Of course this is just a very simple example that can be extended.

```
<span class="math">1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^1 = 1 + 0 + 3 = 5</span>
<script>
    (function(){
        function convert(str) {
            str = str.replace(/\*/g, "&#183;");
            str = str.replace(/\^(.)\s/g, "<sup>$1</sup> ");
            return str;
        };

        var math = document.getElementsByClassName("math");
        for (var i = 0, l = math.length; i < l; ++i) {
            math[i].innerHTML = convert(math[i].innerHTML);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

[Demo (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/Nczp9/)

However, as @Mathias suggested, [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is definitely worth a look if you want to display more complex mathematics.

Comment: that would do it... mathjax seems better for complex maths as you said but for now that will suffice... thanks